# Using Tkinter in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tkinter

I have just started using Tkinter and trying to create a simple pop-up box in python. I have copy pasted a simple code from a website:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="First Name").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Last Name").grid(row=1)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

mainloop( )
```

This code is taking really long time to run, it has been almost 5 minutes!
Is it not possible to just run this snippet?
Can anybody tell me how to use Tkinter?

I am using jupyter notebook and python version 2.7. I would request a solution for this version only.

Comment: What is the problem? Your code is running fine for me. It immediately displays a form with two fields, as expected.

Comment: There is no error in the script. It works fine. Do you want to know how to run this snippet? Copy paste code to your editor, save it, (sample.py), run it using python3 sample.py in terminal. And do you want a pop up from tkinter master or just 2 text boxes in tkinter?

Comment: @DeathJack2.0 just a little correction: python2 ** or `from tkinter import *`

Comment: @DeathJack2.0, i am using jupyter notebook and probably this is the reason the code is not working. For my actual code, i need a pop-up box that appears at the start of my code which asks for user-input which is the path in the local directory. So that, i dont need to do any manipulations in the code.

Comment: @sky_bird. You did not mention you used Jupyter in your question. I thought the problem was the python/tkinter.

Comment: I would add that to my question. Could you help me now?

Comment: Your code runs fine, the problem is Jupyter. Try to run this with a normal interpreter and see what it does.

Comment: @sky_bird, request you to copy paste your code to the bottom of all functions and let root.mainloop() be the last line of the file. It should work

Comment: The pop-up box was appearing as a jupyter file on my system which i missed. Although the code kept running but the box appeared very early. I am really sorry for the long confusion!!

Comment: @DeathJack2.0   I am unable to close question..:( But, i need an extra help. When i am entering something in the box that appears, how to make use of that. Suppose, i want to print the contents of the box that i entered. Could you help me with this?

Comment: @sky_bird Have modified the answer as per requirement.

Comment: @DeathJack2.0    Thanx a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from Tkinter import *

def printData(firstName, lastName):
    print(firstName)
    print(lastName)
    root.destroy()

def get_input():

    firstName = entry1.get()
    lastName = entry2.get()
    printData(firstName, lastName)


root = Tk()
#Label 1
label1 = Label(root,text = 'First Name')
label1.pack()
label1.config(justify = CENTER)

entry1 = Entry(root, width = 30)
entry1.pack()

label3 = Label(root, text="Last Name")
label3.pack()
label1.config(justify = CENTER)

entry2 = Entry(root, width = 30)
entry2.pack()

button1 = Button(root, text = 'submit')
button1.pack() 
button1.config(command = get_input)

root.mainloop()
```

Copy paste the above code into a editor, save it and run using the command,

```
python sample.py
```

*Note: The above code is very vague. Have written it in that way for you to understand.*

Comment: Question about python 2 and your solution is: install python 3? That's weird. Changing imports to make it runnable would be much easier.

Comment: I am using python 2.7 and would not be able to install python 3. Is there a solution for this version?

Comment: @Lafexlos Edited.

Comment: Why use ttk? It's beyond the context.

Comment: The code has been modified, for the context of python 2.7. Works as expected in python 2.x

Comment: The problem is not the code, but Jupyter. The code OP posted runs fine.

Comment: -@right then we need to observe the entire code in that file. @sky_bird, request you to copy paste your code to the bottom of all functions and let root.mainloop() be the last line of the file. It should work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question that was asked, nor does it use any of the code in the original question or explain why completely different code was necessary to solve the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley, the initial question was different and the person who asked kept adding more requirements.

Answer (score 11):

Your code is working just fine. Nevertheless for those using `python3` module name has changed from `Tkinter` to `tkinter` all in lowercase. Edit the name and you're good to go!

In a nutshell.

python2:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

python3:

```
from tkinter import *
```

Look at the screenshot below

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a popup information window as follow:

`showinfo("Window", "Hello World!")`

If you want to create a real popup window with input mask, you will need to generate a new TopLevel mask and open a second window.

```
win = tk.Toplevel()
win.wm_title("Window")

label = tk.Label(win, text="User input")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

button = ttk.Button(win, text="Done", command=win.destroy)
button.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

check it again the code is executing properly but u can't see that output in jupyter notebook itself u can see it in windows column like beside the chrome icons in toggle bar .I'm also confused initially check it once