# Importing Tkinker in Jupyter notebook will not complete

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook, python-import, libraries

When trying to import tkinker into the notebook the cell never ends running

I need to use Tkinker in Jupyter Notebook to create a GUI for an assignment. However I have tried:

```
from tkinter import *

pip install tkinter

install tkinter as TK
```

..and the kernel never completes. Any ideas on what is wrong, not had this problem of kernels not completing and the time taking too long

Comment: You can't install tkinter with pip

Comment: To be specific, `tkinter` is part of the Python standard library, meaning that it already comes as part of the language and does not need to be installed manually. You should be able to use tkinter as is, without installing anything

Comment: Yes, to be even more specific, when you run `from tkinter import *` in a cell, it should run & complete importing. Not keep running. If it imported already, you don't need installation. Whether the code you are using from somewhere else (or developing?) will work is a completely different issue. You probably should insure you can get tkinter working the traditional way on your system (and talk to the people assigning this, perhaps?) following the advice of Right Leg "Try to run this with a normal interpreter and see what it does.", [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45934942/8508004).

Comment: By the way, the steps outlined by [Death Jack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45935231/8508004) in that same thread, cover the basics of using tkinter the traditional way as if it was a typical python script. The details may differ a bit. For example his specific code has the wrong import statement because it was written for Python 2; however, the approach is similar. tkinter predates Jupyter and was meant to provide ways to do much of what elements of the Jupyter ecosystem now provide, see , see [here](https://swan-community.web.cern.ch/t/creating-user-interface-with-tkinter/321/4).